# How to assign weight in Linear layout vertically?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, compatibility

I need to show 3 button in row and 3 button in column means total 9 button on
screen. I assign `android:layout_weight` `0.33` to each in Horizontal LinearLayout. This is compatible with every screen but I need to also set weight vertically.

In Short I need to create one screen with 9 button and it should compatible with every screen. How can I do this? Can we set weight vertically if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 separate LinearLayouts, one for each row, and encapsulate them in a vertical LinearLayout.  Then give the 3 LinearLayouts the same weight.

Pseudo:

```
<VerticalLinearLayout>

    <HorizontalLinearLayout>
        <Button 1 /> 
        <Button 2 />
        <Button 3 />
    </HorizontalLinearLayout>

    <HorizontalLinearLayout>
        <Button 4 />
        <Button 5 />
        <Button 6 />
    </HorizontalLinearLayout>

    <HorizontalLinearLayout>
        <Button 7 />
        <Button 8 />
        <Button 9 />
    </HorizontalLinearLayout>

</VerticalLinearLayout>
```

Give everything a weight of 3, except for the VerticalLinearLayout.  Make sure all of your layout_widths and layout_heights are set to fill_parent.

Comment: maybe you want to have a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4568183/191235

Comment: Thank you! it's work..... Any other way to design screen which compatible with every phone?

Answer (score 0):

**Workable source**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSales"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sales" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnProduction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Production" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Stock" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```